# Files stuck in OneDrive upload queue

Tags: onedrive, photos, windows-10-mobile, uploading, lumia-950

Every once in a while images taken with my Lumia 950 fail to upload to OneDrive. When I open the OneDrive app and check the Camera Roll upload queue, there's one or more files with an error message saying "Sorry, there was a problem. Please try again in a few minutes."

[image]

Selecting the images and then choosing "Try again" or "Remove" does nothing, nor does selecting "Dismiss all errors" from the menu. Is there anything else I can do to remove the images from the queue? Or, at least, figure out which images failed to upload (as there's no thumbnail or filename) so I can transfer them manually?

Answer (score 1):

There has been an update (mostly bug fixes) released for OneDrive in the last few hours. Install it; it may solve your problem.

Comment: Updating OneDrive has not fixed the issue for me, it still happens every now and then (though possibly less frequently).